# Node js запустить скрипт

Tags: node.js, javascript

Как запустить скрипт по пути `C:\Program Files\nodejs\files\hallo.js`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Поместите "hallo.js" в папку "Мои документы" и выполните в "Командная строка" команду "node ./example.js" (без скобок конечно). Для того, чтоб запускать файл из произвольной директории (папки) погуглите [команду 'cd' для windows](https://www.google.com.ua/search?site=&source=hp&q=windows+cd+command&oq=windows+cd&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l10.1287.5463.0.7016.10.8.0.2.2.0.160.935.2j6.8.0....0...1c.1.43.hp..0.10.952.sS-Xuvs79pU). И приведите содержимое файла hallo.js

Comment: вообще, мне надо написать чат
но пока я только установил node.js
не имею понятия как , что и куда писать

Comment: не скоро у вас чат будет. это асинхронность выносит мозг поначалу. Обязательно посмотрите [это][1]

[1]: http://learn.javascript.ru/nodejs-screencast

Comment: спасибо
а на Denver с сокетами монжно работать?

Comment: Denver-ом  в жизни не пользовался. Отдельный вопрос задайте.

Answer (score 6):

Если у вас доступна команда `node` из командной строки, то в общем случае:

```
node /path/to/file/file.js
```

Если нет, то:

```
path/to/nodejs/folder/node /path/to/file/file.js
```

Comment: а почему node C:\Program Files\nodejs\files\hallo.js не работает?
можно, то что вы написали с моим моим путем?!

Comment: Для начала покажите скриншот ошибки